# Update xml file with foreach in C#

Tags: c#, xml

hi I have a xml file like bellow :

```
<page>
  <DOC>
    <DOCID>1</DOCID>
    <CAT>news</CAT>
    <DATE>2015</DATE>
    <CAT>sport</CAT>
    <DOM>News</DOM>
    <LANG>ARabic</LANG>
    <AUT>author</AUT>
    <TITLE>title</TITLE>
    <BODY></BODY>
  </DOC>
  <DOC>
    <DOCID>1</DOCID>
    <CAT>news</CAT>
    <DATE>2015</DATE>
    <CAT>sport</CAT>
    <DOM>News</DOM>
    <LANG>ARabic</LANG>
    <AUT>author</AUT>
    <TITLE>title</TITLE>
    <BODY></BODY>
  </DOC>
  <DOC>
    <DOCID>1</DOCID>
    <CAT>news</CAT>
    <DATE>2015</DATE>
    <CAT>sport</CAT>
    <DOM>News</DOM>
    <LANG>ARabic</LANG>
    <AUT>author</AUT>
    <TITLE>title</TITLE>
    <BODY></BODY>
  </DOC>
</page>
```

How I can Update the second `DOC` node? I want change some value for example change language to `EN` or...

I found it but it removes the first node under `DOC` node and add a node by name `CAT`.

```
        XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();

        xml.Load(FileAddress);
        foreach (XmlElement element in xml.SelectNodes("//DOC"))
        {
            foreach (XmlElement element2 in element)
            {
                if (element.SelectSingleNode("//DOCID").InnerText == datas[PageNow].DOCID)
                {
                    XmlNode newvalue = xml.CreateElement("CAT");
                    newvalue.InnerText = "aaaaaaa";
                    element.ReplaceChild(newvalue, element2);
                    xml.Save(FileAddress);

                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Linq-for-XML:

```
var xml = XDocument.Load(FileAddress);

xml.Root.Elements("DOC").Skip(1).First().Element("LANG").Value = "EN";
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`XElement`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement(v=vs.110).aspx) - following snippet changes the `LANG` node of the second `DOC` node to `EN`:

```
var xml = XDocument.Load(FileAddress);           // load the file
var docs = xml.Descendants("DOC").ToArray();     // get the "DOC" nodes as an array
var lang = docs[1].Descendants("LANG").First();  // get the "LANG" node
lang.Value = "EN";                               // change its value
xml.Save(FileAddress);                           // save the file
```

*ATTENTION*: This code does not contain any checks, like "is there an element at index 1".
See [THIS](https://dotnetfiddle.net/WdgPPj) fiddle to se it in action.